# ¿Cómo subir imágenes con peso mayor a 999KB a phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, imagen, xampp

Estoy cargando imágenes desde un formulario en HTML a una base de datos en phpmyadmin a través de XAMPP, las imágenes suben súper bien. El problema es cuando intento subir imágenes con peso mayor a 999KB, estas no suben a la base de datos. Aclaro que tengo configurado el campo con LONGBLOB. Y así subo la imagen:

```
        $fotoTemporal = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
        $tipoImagen = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
        $nombreFoto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
        $tamanoArchivo = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
        $imagenGuardar = addslashes(file_get_contents($fotoTemporal));


        if($conexion){
            echo "Conectó ";
            $queryDatos = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen (nombre,imagen,tipo,IDAbogado) VALUES ('$nombreFoto','$imagenGuardar','$tipoImagen','NULL')";
            $insertar = $conexion->query($queryDatos);

            if($insertar){
                echo "Archivo subido correctamente";
            }else{
                echo "Ha fallado la subida reintentelo nuevamente";
            }
        }
```

También modifiqué en el archivo php.ini, los valores de los siguientes campos:

- memory_limit: 512M
- post_max_size: 0M
- upload_max_filesize: 220M

Alguien sabría que podría hacer para que las imágenes más pesadas se carguen en la base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_max_size` debe ser `0` en vez de `0M`. Con `0M` estás indicando que el post tiene que tener un tamaño máximo de 0 MB, y con `0` indicas que el tamaño del post no tiene límite.

De todos modos, mi consejo es que no guardes las imágenes directamente en la base de datos.

Según mi experiencia, lo mejor es guardar las imágenes en el servidor y guardar la ruta hacia esa imagen en la base de datos.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
$directorioFotos = '/ruta/hasta/carpeta/fotos';
$fotoTemporal = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$nombreFoto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$tipoImagen = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
// Crea un nombre único con el timestamp para evitar problemas con archivos con el mismo nombre.
$nuevoNombre = time() . '-' . $nombreFoto;
$imagenGuardar = $directorioFotos . '/' . $nuevoNombre;

move_uploaded_file($fotoTemporal, $imagenGuardar);

if($conexion){
    echo "Conectó ";
    $queryDatos = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen (nombre,imagen,tipo,IDAbogado) VALUES ('$nombreFoto','$imagenGuardar','$tipoImagen',NULL)";
    $insertar = $conexion->query($queryDatos);

    if($insertar){
        echo "Archivo subido correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "Ha fallado la subida reinténtelo nuevamente";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por la sugerencia :D, me sirvió muchísimo